# How to write a push function that works with a linked list?

Tags: c, stack

I am writing an exercise program where i am told to write a stack handling program that works with a linked list. Here is the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct stackNode {
   char data;
   struct stackNode *nextPtr;
};

typedef struct stackNode StackNode;
typedef struct stackNode *StackNodePtr;

void push(StackNodePtr *topPtr, char value)
{
    StackNodePtr firstNode = *topPtr;
    while (1) {
        if (*topPtr == NULL) {
            *topPtr = (StackNodePtr) malloc(sizeof(StackNode));
            if (*topPtr == NULL) {
                puts("Error: Out of memory for push.");
                return;
            }
            (*topPtr)->nextPtr = NULL;
            (*topPtr)->data = value;
            break;
        }
        *topPtr = (*topPtr)->nextPtr;
    }
    *topPtr = firstNode;
}

int main()
{
   StackNodePtr stack = NULL;
   push(&stack, 'c'); // Program terminates in this function
   putchar(stack->data);
   return 0;
}
```

I haven't declared & implemented the *pop* function because i have no problem with it. The problem is with the *push* function. I expected the program to push 'c' character in the stack and then print it, but it terminates. Can you correct my code?

Comment: `*topPtr = firstNode;` You first `*topPtr = malloc`. Then you just `break` and overwrite it with initial value. What should happen with `firstNode`?

Comment: There is no need to special case initial insertion on a stack. Allocate a new node, set the new node's `next` to the current stack top (which may be null), set the node's value member, and finally set the stack to to be the new node. Done. No loops. Unrelated, hiding pointer types in typedef aliases is neither helpful nor necessary. There are but two cases where it is genuinely advantageous (black box "handle" APIs, and callback function specifications), and this is neither of those.  C programmers *want* to see asterisks. Believe me.

Comment: Typedeffing pointers is not necessary, but I would argue that it can be helpful.  If clearly identified as a pointer, (as OP does above with the 'Ptr' suffix), it avoids explicit double pointers.  I find this clearer and cleaner than a plague of stars:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your push is needlessly looping, and needlessly trying to account for a case you honestly shouldn't care about one way or the other (whether `*topPtr` is null or not):

```
void push(StackNode **topPtr, char value)
{
    StackNode *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
    if (p != NULL)
    {
        p->data = value;
        p->next = *topPtr;
        *topPtr = p;
    }
    else
    {
        perror("Failed to push value on stack");
    }
}
```

That's it. Your original code looks like you're trying to implement a *queue*, not a stack. Different beasts. Stack is actually easier, as it requires no need to hobble to the opposite end of the sequence prior to insertion.

Comment: I know the difference between stack and queue. I was confused about the way the exercise book wanted me to do it.

Answer (score -1):

the problem is the last line of push function assigns null to stack pointer. and when you call putchar(stack->data); it crashes.
try the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct stackNode {
   char data;
   struct stackNode *nextPtr;
};

typedef struct stackNode StackNode;
typedef struct stackNode *StackNodePtr;

void push(StackNodePtr *topPtr, char value)
{
    StackNodePtr firstNode = *topPtr;
    while (1) {
        if (*topPtr == NULL) {
            *topPtr = (StackNodePtr) malloc(sizeof(StackNode));
            if (*topPtr == NULL) {
                puts("Error: Out of memory for push.");
                return;
            }
            (*topPtr)->nextPtr = NULL;
            (*topPtr)->data = value;
            break;
        }
        *topPtr = (*topPtr)->nextPtr;
    }

}

int main()
{
   StackNodePtr stack = NULL;
   push(&stack, 'c'); // Program terminates in this function
   putchar(stack->data);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For example, if you want to implement your stack as an array , and define your stackNode pointer, using the array doubling technique:

```
 // InitialSize
 static const int InitialSize = 1;

 typedef struct IntegerStackObj{
     int* item;         // array of IntegerStack items
     int numItems;      // number of items in this IntegerStack
     int physicalSize;  // current length of underlying array
 } IntegerStackObj;

typedef struct IntegerStackObj* IntegerStack;

//doubleItemArray
// Doubles the physical size of the underlying array S->item.
void doubleItemArray(IntegerStack S){
     int i;
     int* newArray;
     int* oldArray = S->item;
     S->physicalSize *= 2;
     newArray = calloc(S->physicalSize, sizeof(int));
     for( i=0; i<(S->numItems); i++){
     newArray[i] = oldArray[i];
     }
     S->item = newArray;
     free(oldArray);
}

// push()
// Inserts int x into S on top of the stack
void push(IntegerStack S, int x){

if( S==NULL ){
      fprintf(stderr, "IntegerStack Error: push() called on NULL IntegerStack 
      reference");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }

// increase physical size of array if necessary

if( (S->numItems)==(S->physicalSize) ){
     doubleItemArray(S);
    }

S->item[S->numItems] = x;

S->numItems++;
}
```